# ionic 2 project creation issue in command line

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to create an ionic 2 project through command line but not able to create the project.
i have installed **nodeJS v6.9.2**, **npm version 2.15.11** and **cordova 6.4.0** but getting the following error

```
E:\ionic_test>ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2
```

Creating an Ionic 2.x app in `E:\ionic_test\MyIonic2Project` based on the tutorial template.

```
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error with start Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
Error Initializing app: Error: read ECONNRESET
 Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

I am on windows 10 64bit dont have the admin rights but if i try to download the https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip file from browser
i am able to get the file.

Comment: I downloaded latest cordova and ionic on free network and able to create ionic project by executing the command E:\ionic_test>ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2 ....

Comment: The problem was network when I switched to private network from company network it worked .

Answer (score 1):

Ok Brother, Ionic Utility is not installed in your folder **ionic_test**.
Before creating any app, it's compulsory to create the ionic seed project using this command:

```
E:\ionic_test>npm install -g ionic
```

Or if you are using cordova plugins as well, better play safe with:

```
E:\ionic_test>npm install -g ionic cordova
```

And then create any app you want. Be it:

```
E:\ionic_test>ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2
```

Hopefully, this would solve your problem.